# how to tell .NET not to terminate an application once it determines that an exception that is going to be thrown is not going to be caught?

Tags: c#, .net

There are some cases where control won't pass through the finally block of a try-catch-finally statement when the .NET framework determines that exceptions thrown by the catch block are not going to be caught anywhere in the code.

Can this behavior be configured, and if so how?

(Before you tell me that control ALWAYS passes through the finally block, feel free to conduct the following experiment and report your observations.)

1. In VS, create a console application project
2. Place a try-catch-finally statement inside the Main() method of the console application
3. Write some code inside the finally block or a place breakpoint or anything that will allow you to tell whether control passed through the finally block.
4. have the try block throw an exception
5. have the catch block catch the exception
6. have the catch block rethrow the exception
7. If the version of VS/.NET installed on your machine behaves like mine does, control won't pass through the finally block.

Comment: what if you put the entire try-catch-finally within another try-catch?

Comment: Post the code you're talking about. I really don't believe you.

Comment: Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the observed behavior is related to the way the VS debugger was configured.

Answer (score 2):

Works as expected when I rethrow the exception, code:

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Start");
        try
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Try");
            throw new Exception("ttt");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Catch");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Finally");
        }
    }
}
```

here is my output from my code:

```
Start
Try
Catch

Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: ttt
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\mckeownto01\Documents\Visual Studio    2010\Projects\MvcApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 21
Finally
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WinForms app, add these lines before `Application.Run(new Form1());` in your `Main` routine.

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
```

And add this method to the `Program` class:

```
static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: Handle the error here.
}
```